# applymap function on a df.copy() changing the original dataframe values

Tags: python, pandas, copy, python-applymap

I have a pandas dataframe called `results` that contain 2 columns, one called `years` containing lists of years and another called `line_items` containing lists of integers. I am trying to sort the list values in a copy of the original dataframe, called `dfcopy` but so that it DOESNT CHANGE THE ORIGINAL DATAFRAME. The two reproducible dfs are as such:

```
results = {'years': {0: ['2020', '2021'], 1: ['2019', '2020'], 2: ['2020', '2021'], 3: ['2019', '2020'], 4: ['2019', '2020']}, 'line_items': {0: ['3818', '4121'], 1: ['105', '154'], 2: ['1030', '942'], 3: ['4681', '4849'], 4: ['3439', '3656']}}

dfcopy = results[['years', 'line_items']].copy()
```

I am using an applymap on `dfcopy` to sort the lists which IS changing `results`. This to me makes no sense at all as both my understanding and the docs for `.copy()` suggest that this does not change the original dataframe. Here is my code:

```
dfcopy.applymap(lambda x: x.sort())
```

Can anyone help me to understand why this is happening. (PS I know I could just do results.copy() but this should not change the functionality of the .copy() function)

Answer (score 0):

Because `lambda x: x.sort()` *mutates the list objects in-place*.

And `.copy` does not copy the python objects that happen to be in the dataframe, this won't even happen if you pass `deep=True` to `df.copy`.

In general, pandas is not designed around having lists inside your dataframe.

Comment: I'm confused as to what `.copy()` is for is that case?

Comment: @geds133 it *copies the dataframe*. `copy(deep=False)` will not copy the underlying buffers, but `copy(deep=True)` does.  However, even if you copy the underlying buffers, when you put a list in a dataframe, the dtype *must be `object`*. Which basically just means pointers to python objects. Really, you probably don't want to be using lists inside dataframes

Comment: @geds133 anyway, you could just do `dfcopy.applymap(sorted)`